# Checking that a mapping between measurable spaces is measurable by checking only the collection that generates the sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

[image]A similar question has been asked but this one is more focused on a particular detail. The assumption is that $f$ is measurable with respect to sets in $\mathcal{F}_0$. I understand why $\mathcal{F}_1$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and I understand why $\mathcal{F}_0 \subset \mathcal{F}_1$, but how does it follow that then $f$ is measurable with respect to all sets in $\mathcal{F}$, when the assumption is that $f$ is measurable only with respect to sets in $\mathcal{F}_0$?

$\mathcal{F}_0$ should equal $\mathcal{F}_1$ by the above assumption. I struggle to find coherence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal F_1$ is sigma algebra and $\mathcal F$ is, by assumption, the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal F_0$. This means $\mathcal F$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal F_0$. Hence $\mathcal F=\sigma (\mathcal F_0 )\subset \mathcal F_1$. What does this say? If $E \in \mathcal F$ then $E \in \mathcal F_1$. By definition of $\mathcal F_1$ this means $f$ is measurable.

Comment: But $f$ was defined only on $\mathcal{F}_0$. Why then define it for all $B$ in $\mathcal{F}$...

Comment: What do you man by saying that $f$ is defined only on $\mathcal F_0$? $f$ is a function  from $E$ to $F$. @PetarJovanovski

Comment: It seems like I don't understand the part where $f$ is measurable w.r.t $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}_0$ can be extended to $f$ measurable w.r.t $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}_1$ is artificially constructed.

Comment: Most results involving sigma algebra generated by a  class of sets are proved by introducing a new class of sets, proving that it is a sigma algebra containing the given class and then using the definition of the sigma algebra generated by a class of sets. @PetarJovanovski

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot :)